# IE8 minimizing automatically while opening a website using Visual Studio 2012 or direct URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**IE8 is getting minimized** automatically when opening a website using `Visual Studio 2012` or direct URL. This is not happening on IE9+ version and does not happen if I first open a blank tab then website. I have tried disabling all add-ons but issue still persists. I am using `Jquery`, `Javascript` and `HTML5` for development.
Please suggest.

Comment: Life is hard with IEs. Not possible to help you without seeing your code.

Comment: the code is huge, which portion should i show you?